# What's the best way to integrate PyroCMS into an existing CodeIgniter 2.x webapp?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

I want to use PyroCMS as a basic CMS for a webapp front end pages (home, privacy policy, about, contact, etc.).  I already have my webapp started using CodeIgniter 2.x.

Anybody know the best way to "bolt on" PyroCMS to my existing CodeIgniter webapp, so that I can use PyroCMS to add/edit/manage pages within my database, and use custom code in my webapp to read/view those pages on the webapp front end?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create your webapp as a module in the PyroCMS system.

Place all the contents of your application directory inside the new module.

Comment: Thanks Yan.  I assume this doc on the PyroCMS site is the best way to go?
http://www.pyrocms.com/docs/2.0/developers/creating-custom-modules

Comment: Also, going this route, will my webapp still be the "main" portion of the entire project?  Put differently, all my URL structures and routes remain in place, right?

Comment: You are correct. That link is a good start. Regarding routes: On default your webapp will be called like this: `example.com/webapp_module_name/controller_name/method`. In order to modify that behavior you will need to add the routes module.